# Trie for numbers

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, trie

Is it good idea to use trie or DAWG for numbers instead of strings? I have many two numbers combinations and want to decrease required memory size.

I would like to be able to store all the numbers combination, but if the data structure only supports queries to check if a give combination exists among the given ones I will be happy.

Comment: Do you intend to frequently query the sequences by prefix?

Comment: @Colonel Panic I donn't use prefix. Input is two numbers. Output is true\false or other number(prefer)

Comment: If the memory savings are worth the added complexity, why not?

Comment: @Neir0, if not, then no.

Comment: everyone I believe this question is reasonable only that it was not put clearly. I have attempted to edit it to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @nwellnhof Sure. But maybe there are exist better data structure for such data type

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the optimization for 2-digit numbers will be too great. But for longer numbers a TRIE definitely seems like a good solution.

As for the two digit combinations I think it is best to use an array of size 100 that stores a flag(or count if repetition is allowed) corresponding to each of the 100 two digit combinations. Of course if only numbers are allowed you will only need 90 places as the 10 combinations starting with 0 are not valid numbers. When inserting a number simply set the corresponding flag in the array(constant computational complexity). When checking if a number is found in the set simply check the corresponding flag in the array(again constant complexity). To recover all the numbers you have, iterate over the array and print all numbers that have their corresponding flags set. My idea is somewhat similar to set sort and when repetition is allowed to [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). This solution also has the best possible computational complexity- constant for both operations.